# Calculating optimum values of $u$ and $m$ from $\mathbb V(\bar {y_2}\prime)=\frac{S_2^2(n-u\rho^2)}{n^2-u^2\rho^2}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, statistics, statistical-inference

I have to find optimum sample size in sampling on two occasions.

Suppose that the samples are of the same size n on both occasions. In selecting the second sample, $m$ of the units in the first sample are retained. The remaining $u$ units are discarded and replaced by a new selection from the units not previously selected.

Notation:

$\bar y_{hu}=$mean of unmatched portion on occasion $h$

$\bar y_{hm}=$mean of matched portion on occasion $h$

$\bar y_{h}=$mean of whole sample on occasion $h$

$$\mathbb V(\bar {y_2}\prime)=\frac{S_2^2(n-u\rho^2)}{n^2-u^2\rho^2}\ldots(1)$$

$\rho$ denotes correlation coefficient

The optimum value of $u$ is found by minimizing equation (1) with respect to variation in $u$.This gives
$$\frac{u}{n}=\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\ldots (2)$$ 
How they derived equation (2) from (1)?

I supposed to differentiate (1) with respect to $u$ and set it to zero. But i couldn't remove $S_2^2$ of equation (1) to derive (2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I differentiate $\mathbb V(\overline{y}_2')$ it gives: $\frac{S_2^2\cdot \rho^2 \cdot (n^2-2nu + \rho^2u^2)}{(n^2-u^2\rho ^2)^2}$

To get the fraction equal to zero, $n^2-2nu + \rho^2u^2$ has to be zero, if $S_2^2\cdot \rho^2 \neq 0$ . To solve this equation, you can use the the general formula to solve an quadratic equation:

$x_{1,2}=\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$

Here is $a=\rho ^2, b=-2n$ and $c=n^2$

Comment: I come up with $\frac{u}{n}=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}{\rho^2}$     which does not match with equation (2). In the book, it is written that they have minimized equation (1) w.r.to `variation` in $u$ . Am i focusing in wrong word?

Comment: It looks fine. From your result you take only the one with the minus sign: $\frac{u}{n}=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\rho ^2}}{\rho ^2}$ Thus you multiply the numerator and the denominator with $1+\sqrt{1-\rho ^2}$. For the numerator it is useful to know the third binomial formula.